# drupal_add_js - working with inline but not file

Tags: 7, javascript

I am using the following code, which works.

```php
function mymodulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'job_node_form') {
    drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });', 'inline');
  }
}
```

The following code doesn't work.

```php
function mymodulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'job_node_form') {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module','conflict') . '/js/test.js');
  }
}
```

The code in sites/all/modules/mymodulename/js/test.js is the following.

```javascript
if (Drupal.jsEnabled) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Hello!");
  });
}
```

When I look at the page source, I can see the JavaScript file is loaded.

Is the inline code timed differently to the code in a JavaScript file?

Comment: Propably `jsEnabled` not defened yet, moreover if browser unsupports js, whole code will not able to execute. 
Try this `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { alert('123'); });` in your file or try `$form['#attached']['js'][] = array('data' => 'path_to_js_file.js', 'type' => 'file');`

Comment: Additionally, the script may be loading before jQuery -- what errors do you see in Firebug/Inspector? Try adding the group parameter THEME, or a low weight (see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7 for options.)

Comment: Or module named mymodule and you try to load file from "conflict" module, that doesn't exists. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Drupal, instead of using `$(document).ready`, you should use [Drupal behaviors](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/managing-javascript-in-drupal-7#behaviors). The equivalent of the JavaScript code in the test.js file shown in the question would be the following one.

```javascript
(function($, Drupal) {

  Drupal.behaviors.moduleName = {
    attach:function() {
      alert("Hello!");
    }
  };
}(jQuery, Drupal));
```

I would rather not use `drupal_add_js()`. Instead, the code can attach JavaScript to the form array, as the following code does.

```php
if ($form_id == 'job_node_form') {
  $form['#attached']['js'][] = array(
    'type' => 'file',
    'data' => drupal_get_path('module','conflict') . '/js/test.js',
  );
}
```

This attaches the file directly to the form, allowing it to be removed/replaced by another module that implements [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x), [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x), [`hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7.x).

Using `#attached` is also the method that [Managing JavaScript](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/managing-javascript-in-drupal-7) says it's preferred over `drupal_add_js()` because the reference to the file is cached, whereas `drupal_add_js()` requires a function call to add the script to the page. In some case, for example `hook_block_view()`, `drupal_add_js()` won't be called when the block is cached, while the `#attached` array would be added from `hook_block_view()` before the block is cached.